# Oracle client , Instant client and ODAC

Tags: oracle, oracle11gr2, oracleclient, odac

I want to download the full oracle client 11.2.0.4, but the only download I found in oracle website is Oracle Instant client.
Can I get a direct link to the download in Oracle website ?

Another thing, I need also the ODAC for .Net, does it include in the Oracle Client ? Or would I need to download it separately.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Version 11.2.0.4 is not publicly available, it can be downloaded from support.oracle.com - including the full client. In order to log in there, you need an account associated with a valid CSI number (support contract).

ODAC includes the Instant client, you don't need to download and install a seperate Oracle client software.

The direct link anyways is as follows (but you need an account with the proper privileges to download it):

https://updates.oracle.com/Orion/Services/download/p13390677_112040_MSWIN-x86-64_4of7.zip?aru=16908159&patch_file=p13390677_112040_MSWIN-x86-64_4of7.zip

Comment: Thanks about the first question. About the ODAC.. In full Oracle Client, does ODAC comes with it? Or will I have to Install ODAC separately?

Comment: ODAC is just a collection of components related to Windows and .NET. The full client contains all these components and you don't have to install ODAC seperately, if you have the full client.